# Accessing Rental History

Tags: usa, real-estate

I'm able to access my county's Public Record system to look a historical information (owner's names, taxes, etc) for a given property. Is there a similar means to access the same history, but with renting tenants?

Example:

https://www.skagitcounty.net/Search/Property/?id=P107482

Similar to [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10477/rental-loan-agreement-document-database), but I'm looking for a link between name and address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - no

---

A landowner had both legal rights and responsibilities (such as paying taxes) so ownership needs to be tracked by the state and is a pubic record.  A tenant; however, has no public responsibility.  His responsibility is to the owner. This certainly can vary by state; but, I have never heard of any responsibility to register a property's tenant - only its owner.

Someone might be able to infer tenancy from a person's current address; but, registering your address does not necessarily mean you pay the rent.  "Everything is on the internet"; so, I wouldn't be surprised if someone figured out a way to determine it (like from instance from utility bills); but, I doubt you'll find it on a state registry.

I skimmed the [Washington Rental Laws](https://www.landlordology.com/washington-landlord-tenant-laws/) and I didn't see anything.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I didn't think to look at other sources like postal registration, that should be sufficient for what I'm doing if something exists.